# Menorah a way to wipe out Amalek and tool which helps us not to 'cool off'?

Tags: commentaries, amalek, menorah--in-temple, tetzaveh, parshat-zachor

This year one will read the Torah portion of Tetzaveh and the special designated Torah reading for the Shabbat prior to Purim, known as Shabbat Zachor, together.

Rabbeinu Yehuda Aryeh DiModina (Yid Hakadosh) in another year when this happened would say: “Parshas Zachor is read on the week of Parshas Tetzaveh. Why? Because Amalek’s entire goal was to ‘cool off’ the burning enthusiasm of the Jewish people and cause them to lose focus. Tetzaveh begins with lighting the Menorah, when we ignite and inflame our passion for Hashem and His Torah. What better time to heat up the coldness and wipe out Amalek?”

Now here's my question:
How does the Menorah become a way to wipe out Amalek and a tool which helps us not to 'cool off'?

How is it that the Menorah helps one to ignite and inflame one's passion in order that one loses his or her coldness or protect one from even becoming 'cold' in the first place? How can a Menorah help me wipe out Amalek in my life?

Comment: It would help much if you can provide a link to the source of this statement, esp. when you refer to a lesser known name. Note that on leap years, parshat Zachor does not occur on parshat tetzaveh.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the name of the Yid Hakadosh? I think this was someone else https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_of_Modena

Comment: @DanF I guess his source is from here: http://www.torahtavlin.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/19-Tetzaveh.pdf it's a literal quotation as presented in the question

Comment: @Levi I need a bigger screen or glasses to read that article. Have to try, later. I suggest that you put a link to this in OP's question. I don't know how you found this, but, this source page seems quite obscure.

Comment: @DanF Levi was correct, got it from the TorahTavlin.org website; you can open it with a pdf reader like Adobe and then zoom in, in such case it's really easy to read. But I can't figure out from where (which commentary, sefer) this quotation came from.

Comment: @ba DiModina could be Mi-Modena, but I've never heard of both names, so I simply don't know